I can't seem to reflect my lists with my updated data whenever position is changing
I've been sitting with this problem for days, and I can't quite figure out what's wrong with my code.
My problem is that whenever my data gets re-ordered or change position, like changing the tabs position, the values don't properly reflect. I'm so burnt out with this problem and I can't really think straight anymore.
I regretted using index as my identifier, but in this case, which I'm really sure, doesn't have any affect on how my data is being displayed. Please help! Thank you.
My popup.js
let data_placeholder = {};
initialize_data();

// Update the storage after the popup is closed
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "set_data", data: data_placeholder });
});

// Update data_placeholder everytime the checkbox is toggled
function update_data(checkbox, type, index, method) {
    if (checkbox.nodeName == "INPUT" && checkbox.type == "checkbox") {
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
            data_placeholder[type][index][method] = checkbox.checked;
        });
    } else {
        console.warn("This shouldn't be happening: Error(Incompatible type)");
    }
}

// Execute script
document.getElementById("execute-script").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        message: "execute_methods",
        data: data_placeholder,
    });
});

// some code

function initialize_data() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "get_data" }, (data) => {
        // Update data_placeholder with the latest data
        data_placeholder = structuredClone(data);
        console.log("Popup data: ", data_placeholder);
        if (data.extensions.length > 0) {
            let frag_ext = document.createDocumentFragment();
            data.extensions.sort((a, b) => a.ext_name.localeCompare(b.ext_name));
            data.extensions.forEach((extension, i) => {
                // Don't show self
                if (extension.ext_name == "Chroxt") {
                    return;
                }
                // Setting up the elements
                let container = document.createElement("div");
                let name = document.createElement("p");
                let reload = document.createElement("input");
                let uninstall = document.createElement("input");
                let disable = document.createElement("input");
                name.title = `Name: ${extension.ext_name}\nID: ${extension.ext_id}\nVersion: ${extension.version}\nMatches: \n\t${extension.matches.join(",\n\t")}\nPermissions: \n\t${extension.permissions.join(",\n\t")}`;
                name.textContent = extension.ext_name;

                frag_ext.appendChild(batch_append(container, [name, reload, uninstall, disable]));
                batch_set_attr([reload, uninstall, disable], "type", "checkbox");
                container.setAttribute("class", "ext-list-body");

                // Modifying the properties
                reload.checked = extension.reload;
                disable.checked = extension.disable;
                uninstall.checked = extension.uninstall;

                // Adding listeners for checkboxes
                update_data(reload, "extensions", i, "reload");
                update_data(uninstall, "extensions", i, "uninstall");
                update_data(disable, "extensions", i, "disable");

                // Stylization
                if (extension.enabled) {
                    name.style.opacity = "100%";
                } else {
                    name.style.opacity = "30%";
                }
            });
            document.getElementById("list-ext").appendChild(frag_ext);
        } else {
            // Add such empty
        }

        if (data.websites.length > 0) {
            let frag_site = document.createDocumentFragment();
            data.websites.forEach((website, i) => {
                // Setting up the elements
                let container = document.createElement("div");
                let name = document.createElement("p");
                let reload = document.createElement("input");
                name.title = `Title: ${website.site_name}\nID: ${website.site_id}\nURL: ${website.url}`;
                name.textContent = website.site_name;

                frag_site.appendChild(batch_append(container, [name, reload]));
                reload.type = "checkbox";
                container.setAttribute("class", "site-list-body");

                // Modifying the properties
                reload.checked = website.reload;

                // Adding listeners for checkbox
                update_data(reload, "websites", i, "reload");
            });
            document.getElementById("list-site").appendChild(frag_site);
        } else {
            // Add such empty
        }
    });
}


background.js
let storage = chrome.storage.local;

// Purpose: Get new extensions & tabs data, default if new, otherwise copy methods data from original
// Return: Return an object, not merged with old data, but with old data essential properties
// Nutshell: Returns new & updated data
function get_new_data(callback = null) {
    let data_placeholder = {
        extensions: [],
        websites: [],
        enabled: false,
        "show-popup": true,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Get the current strorage
        storage.get(null, (data) => {
            // Get new extensions and new extension properties
            chrome.management.getAll((extensions) => {
                extensions.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                extensions.forEach((ext, i) => {
                    // Since PWA is included, only allow extensions
                    if (ext.type == "extension") {
                        // Create an object inside an array of this object for every extension
                        data_placeholder.extensions[i] = {
                            // Brand new data
                            ext_name: ext.name,
                            ext_id: ext.id,
                            version: ext.version,
                            enabled: ext.enabled,
                            matches: ext.hostPermissions,
                            permissions: ext.permissions,
                            icon: ext.icons?.[0].url,

                            // Keep settings the same, if not initialized, set to default
                            reload: data.extensions?.[i]?.reload ?? false,
                            disable: data.extensions?.[i]?.disable ?? false,
                            uninstall: data.extensions?.[i]?.uninstall ?? false,
                        };
                    }
                });
                // After extension operation, get all open tabs
                chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
                    tabs.forEach((tab, k) => {
                        // For each tab, add this object
                        data_placeholder.websites[k] = {
                            site_name: tab.title,
                            site_id: tab.id,
                            icon: tab.favIconUrl,
                            url: tab.url,

                            // Keep settings the same, if not initialized, set to default
                            reload: data.websites?.[k]?.reload ?? false,
                        };
                    });
                    // Finally, return the merged data through Promises or callback
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback(data_placeholder);
                    } else {
                        resolve(data_placeholder);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((receive, _, send) => {
    switch (receive.message) {
        case "get_data":
            get_new_data().then((data) => {
                send(data);
                console.log("Background: ", data);
            });
            break;
        case "set_data":
            storage.set(receive.data);
            break;
        case "execute_methods":
            receive.data.extensions.forEach((extension) => {
                if (extension.reload) {
                    chrome.management.setEnabled(extension.ext_id, false);
                    chrome.management.setEnabled(extension.ext_id, true);
                }
                if (extension.disable) {
                    chrome.management.setEnabled(extension.ext_id, !extension.enabled);
                }
                if (extension.uninstall) {
                    chrome.management.uninstall(extension.ext_id);
                }
            });
            receive.data.websites.forEach((website) => {
                if (website.reload) {
                    chrome.tabs.reload(website.site_id);
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            console.warn("UNHANDLED MESSAGE: ONMESSAGE");
            break;
    }
    return true;
});


I tried using ID as identifier using find(), but it produces the same result. I'm new with JS object concepts, and I've been trying to find a course or study materials on how to make data consistent everywhere and I couldn't find any materials.

https://github.com/yvantot/chroxt if you'd like to try my code, it's in here. If no hope, I'll rewrite my code for the 3rd time.

Welcome to SO! What happens when debugging?

Yeah, that's what spinning my head. I couldn't locate where I'm doing wrong. My best bet is that my initial_data function, I'll just rewrite it.
